# How to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 component only

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

Below is a list of the SQL components that I installed in the Visual Studio 2010 Professional setup. Sadly, while trying to work I could not find [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) 2008.

Is there a way to download SQL Server Management Studio 2008 separately and install only that component?

Since in the past I installed SQL Server Management Studio 2005 with a whole new instance of [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) and had couple of instances, and it was a bit messy.

[image]

Comment: SSMS 2008 Express is a free download, assuming it meets your needs...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834191/sql-server-management-studio-missing# The last answer in this topic was the key for me. good luck.

Comment: Why is this closed?  The [defined by the community](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) link above includes "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have the SQL Server 2008 Installation media, you can install just the Client/Workstation Components.  You don't have to install the database engine to install the workstation tools, but if you plan to do Integration Services development, you do need to install the Integration Services Engine on the workstation for BIDS to be able to be used for development.  Keep in mind that Visual Studio 2010 does not have BI development support currently, so you have to install BIDS from the SQL Installation media and use the Visual Studio 2008 BI Development Studio that installs under the SQL Server 2008 folder in Program Files if you need to do any SSIS, SSRS, or SSAS development from the workstation.

As mentioned in the comments you can download Management Studio Express free from Microsoft, but if you already have the installation media for SQL Server Standard/Enterprise/Developer edition, you'd be better off using what you have.

[Download SSMS 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

Comment: In the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer, this feature is renamed to 'Management Tools - Basic'.

Comment: +1 for "Better off using what you have," heading me off from installing the express by mistake, so @dyslexicanaboko's answer fit my situation.

Answer (score 142):

I found some articles to be of major use:

This link is an experience someone else had:
http://goneale.com/2009/05/24/cant-install-microsoft-sql-server-2008-management-studio-express/

This link has the exact steps involved to install everything properly:
http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/06/03/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-management-studio/

This link confirms the previous link:
https://superuser.com/questions/88244/installing-sql-server-management-studio-when-vs2010-beta-2-is-already-installed

**My Instructions**

I am not sure if my instructions will be 100% accurate, but in my instance, because I installed VS2010 on a fresh copy of Windows 7, the VS2010 installer installs SQL Server 2008 Express for you, so from this point I just need the Management Studio.

What I gathered from these explanations is to do the following:

1. Download the SQL Server Management Studio install from
   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22973
2. Run the setup, when you get to the point where it asks you to "**Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008**" or "**Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008**", this part is the CONFUSING PART (HEY MICROSOFT TAKE NOTES, DON'T DO THIS KIND OF STUFF).

   As much as you want to select "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008" *DON'T!!!!*

   You need to select "**Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008**". It doesn't sound right I know - it is very confusing and counter intuitive, but this seems to be the way to install management studio. :(
3. Press next until you see the features selection portion. Heeeeeyyyy look at that, it has a check box for Management Studio. It should be selected already, if not then select it of course and press next.
4. Press Next next next next next next... basically just install it at this point.
5. Enjoy, it has installed.

Comment: +1 for "HEY MICROSOFT TAKE NOTES, DON'T DO THIS KIND OF STUFF", but actually I couldn't get the SQL Server 2008 (non-SP) installer to work on my machine (Win7 SP1) - it kept insisting that I needed to reboot, even after a reboot. To be fair though, it did warn me about "known compatibility issues".

Comment: I think I ran into an issue like that before on an XP machine. I could be way off but I think that has something to do with a default set of files existing or something, and until you find and delete it you will continue to have that problem. I think it is in your %appdata%. As far as the constant reboot goes check this out: http://geekswithblogs.net/rowser/archive/2009/03/03/129818.aspx, be sure to post the solution if you find one, now I am curious.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did before, but I ran the setup and it installed everything *except* ssmse.  I was *sure* I had that little box checked.  So, I re-ran it, the box for management studio was already checked, which is confusing.  After wondering for a while, and reading this, I just hit next and hoped that would actually install it.  It did!

Comment: Coming from a LAMP background this is the most frustrating process ever!

Comment: I'm sorry :( but looking on the bright side SQL Server is pretty awesome to use, just not a joy to install. I still get confused about which user account to specify when installing SQL Server itself.

Comment: Wow, that install boasts almost a gigabyte of required space.

Comment: +1 "Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008", I clicked "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008" and got errors, how confusing! thnx a lot!

Comment: I would give you 50 upvotes if I could!

Comment: It's so bad that it's not accepted answer. I lost another 20 seconds (after spending 20 minutes trying to install Management studio..) to read accepted answer ;)

Comment: +1 Of all the options in this wretched installer, none of which did what I wanted, at least I was absolutely sure that I did not want to perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008.  Clearly, Microsoft disagrees.  wtf...

Comment: `Press Next next next next next next... basically just install it at this point.` Note: Be careful. If you'll be using SQL Server in the future, installing it isn't simply just "next next next." There are some additional instructions like adding a user account (SQLAgent etc.) to your computer.

Answer (score 8):

I am just updating this with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 version. if you run the installer normally, you can just add Management Tools – Basic, and by clicking Basic it should select Management Tools – Complete.

That is what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I actually somehow missed this when setting up my first instance. I'm not sure why there wouldn't be an option to install the management studio separately though.

Comment: @zach I know it's old - your link died.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer was correct up until July 2011. To get the latest version, including the Service Pack you should find the latest version as described here:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041

For example, if you check the SP2 CTP and SP1, you'll find the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio under SP1:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727

Download the 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) version of the SQLManagementStudio*.exe files as appropriate and install it. You can find out whether your system is 32-bit or 64-bit by right clicking Computer, selecting Properties and looking at the System Type.

Although you could apply the service pack to the base version that results from following the accepted answer, it's easier to just download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio and simply install it in one step.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727 worked perfect for me - this is the full version of management studio and not express

Comment: I just had the same experience with WIN 7 / 64bit

Answer (score 0):

For any of you still having problems as of Sept. 2012, go here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041  ...and grab the `SQLManagementStudio_x(32|64)_ENU.exe` (if you've already installed SQL Server 2008 Express R2), or SQL Server 2008 Express R2 with Tools, i.e. `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe or SQLEXPRWT_x32_ENU.exe` (if you haven't).

From there, follow similar instructions as above (i.e. use the "Perform new installation and add shared features" selection, as "Management Tools - Basic" is considered a "shared feature"), if you've already installed SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (as I had).  And if you haven't done that yet, then of course you're going to follow this way as you need to install the new instance anyway.

This solved things for me, and hopefully it will for you, too!

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Express commandline:**

The answer by dyslexicanaboko hits the crucial point, but this one is even simpler and suited for command line (unattended scenarios):

(tried out with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, one instance installed and having downloaded SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe)

As pointed out in this thread often enough, it is better to use the original SQL server setup (e.g. SQL Express with Tools), if possible, but there *are* some scenarios, where you want to add SSMS at a SQL derivative without that tools, afterwards:

I´ve already put it in a batch syntax here:

```
@echo off
"%~dp0SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" /Q /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES="SSMS" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Remarks:

1. For 2008 without R2 it should be enough to omit the **/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS** flag, i guess.
2. The **/INDICATEPROGRESS** parameter is useless here, the whole command takes a number of minutes and is 100% silent without any acknowledgement. Just look at the start menu, if the command is ready, if it has succeeded.
3. This should work for the "**ADV_SSMS**" Feature (instead of "SSMS") too, which is the management studio extended variant (profiling, reporting, tuning, etc.)