# SQL Server Management Studio missing

Tags: ssms

I just installed SQL Server 2008 r2 and SQL Server Management Studio.
After installation, I found that the SQL Server Management Studio has not been installed.

I wanted to install SQL Server Management Studio, but cannot find the installation for this. Any idea how to install it?

Comment: Its not missing. Its a different component, try google SSMS installer for setup.

Comment: Why is that thing so complicated to install.  Can't they ship a simple standalone installer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Did you include "Management Tools" as a chosen option during setup?

[image]

Ensure this option is selected, and SQL Server Management Studio will be installed on the machine.

Comment: i did not had this option in setup

Comment: @Pavel: re-run/change your installation options in Windows Control Panel, and you'll be able to select this.

Comment: @p.cambell there was noting like that, i am leaving this alone still thanx

Comment: @Pavel; can you screenshot your installation options window (as above), and paste as a link here?

Comment: Sorry stopped to do that, might try another time later, i know i had only option management tools - basic.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is an old question, but I've just had the same frustrating issue for a couple of hours and wanted to share my solution. In my case the option "Managements Tools" wasn't available in the installation menu either. It wasn't just greyed out as disabled or already installed, but instead just missing, it wasn't anywhere on the menu.

So what finally worked for me was to use the [Web Platform Installer 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), and check this for installation: Products > Database >  "Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Objects". Once this is done, you can relaunch the installation and "Management Tools" will appear like previous answers stated.

Note there could also be a "Sql Server 2012 Shared Management Objects", but I think this is for different purposes.

Hope this saves someone the couple of hours I wasted into this.

Comment: *Hope this saves someone the couple of hours I wasted into this.* It did. Much appreciated. +1.

Comment: This answer = aspirin

Comment: If you're reading this because the Features window isn't even shown, check you're not experiencing: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc874f5f-2e98-4386-81d4-34e72cfa2ab1/errors-with-installation-of-sql-server-2012?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Answer (score 21):

In **SQL Server 2016** it has its own link:

[image]

Just download it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you have a copy of backup of SQL Server setup then you could add features (Management Tools Basic/Complete) as you requested.

Please use the below steps in Windows machine:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Program and Features -> Select your current version of Microsoft SQL Server
2. Right Click, select Change/Uninstall
3. Click Add features
4. Select the backup copy folder
5. Do the steps what you done for SQL Server installation until features selection
6. Now select the features Management Tools Basic/Complete or both
7. And go ahead with process for complete installation.
8. Now you should get, SQL Server Management Studio and you can browse your databases.

Answer (score 1):

**Current version:**

SQL Server Management Studio

Direct link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=828615

Version Information

This release of SSMS uses the Visual Studio 2015 Isolated shell.
The release number: 16.4.1
The build number for this release: 13.0.15900.1
Supported SQL Server versions
This version of SSMS works with all supported versions of SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2016), and provides the greatest level of support for working with the latest cloud features in Azure SQL Database.
There is no explicit block for SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005, but some features may not work properly.
Additionally, one SSMS 16.x release or SSMS 2016 can be installed side by side with previous versions of SSMS 2014 and earlier.

---

Older version of the answer for 2012

Installation steps:

1. Download file "SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe" for your version aprox 1Gb
2. Execute following command (note that installation need access to internet to download about 140Mb and you will need to interact with installer)

**Command:**
SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=TOOLS /QUIETSIMPLE /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms

original answer was:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-r2-profiler
Now posted:
http://blog.cpodesign.com/blog/sql-2012-installing-sql-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

**Try restarting your computer** if you just installed SQL Server and there's no choice in the SQL Server Installation Center to install SQL Server Management Studio.

This choice (see image below) only appeared for me after I installed SQL Server, then restarted my computer:

[image]