# Unable to open SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssms

To download and install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, I followed these steps from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22985:

1. Download and install Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1.
2. Download and install Windows Installer 4.5.
3. Download and install Windows PowerShell 1.0.
4. Download SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Tools by clicking the appropriate link below.

   ```
   SQLManagementStudio_X86 Executable
   ```

but still on searching in start menu, I am just able to see `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Installation Server`.

What should I do to get and open that ide where I can create a database for my applications?

Comment: did you see the [SQL Server Management Studio] that is the IDE

Comment: @ananya Download Managament Studio 2008 R2. Then only you would be able to see that in your start menu.

Comment: no , this is not visbile.
do i have to download it separately?if yes then from where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834191/sql-server-management-studio-missing

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for the EXE; by default it should be in the following location:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe`

You can then create a start menu or quick launch item by dragging the exe there.

If you can't find it, search your hard drive for files called `ssms.exe`.
To do the search I'd suggest Agent Ransack; Windows search is slower and these days aimed more at finding documents than system files: http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack

Answer (score 1):

If you face this problem, just try to look in the folder **ManagementStudio** `("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio" for me)`

If you sort the folder by the type, you will find in application type :  **Ssms**. 
Just dubble click on this and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio wil open.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually install Management Studio? If yes, you should see the icon in Start->All Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2-> SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: yes i have had installed it and the icon in Start menu is like this start->All Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2->  configurations tool -> sql server installation server .

Comment: This means Management Studio is not installed correctly. Run the setup again and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Download Management Studio 2008 R2. Then only you would be able to see that in your start menu

Download link for Management Studio 2008 R2

[Click here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Comment: i have downloaded it from here itself : SQLManagementStudio_X86 Executable

Comment: Press Window key and R Together that will open Run Prompt, type ssms over there and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually install sql server, or just sql management studio?
The management studio only gives you the client and a few other configuration items. You need to install the sql server first, which you can do here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679

Also, be sure to install the management studio that corresponds to you sql server version (else you'll be limited in what operations you can perform on the databases).

If you have trouble finding SSMS client, an easy trick for windows 8 and above is to just type SSMS at the start menu/screen and when you get the icon (a database symbol connected to a hammer/spanner), right-click and pin to start.