# Where to download SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (not express version)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Where can I download that? All I can find is the express version. I bought the SQL Server Developer 2008, but the Studio wasnt installed along with it...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install sql server management studio 2008 component only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536023/how-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2008-component-only)

Answer (score 2):

SSMS is ALWAYS part of any non-express edition including DEV edition (I mean you dont need to download it seperately).

When you install SQL Server Dev. (or any other non-express edition), during setup process you will come across a screen where you can select which components to install (e.g. SSIS, SSRS, SSAS, BIDS, BOL etc). In that step you will need to select SSMS to get it installed.

For some reason if you have skipped that step you can run setup again and just install SSMS only.

But I dont think there is any seperate download available for "normal" SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoyance because access to SQL Server from a workstation is necessary and the only way (as previous posters mentioned) is to use the full SQL Server licensed installation package.

You'll run the setup to install as though you're installing the full database.  In some cases, setup will detect that you'll need to first install some dependencies.  When you come to the Feature Selection, you can select the Management Tools only.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ochff.gif

Answer (score 0):

The express version is the free version. If you want another version you need to buy it. My best guess is that it is included in one of those packages on in the [microsoft store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store?defaultKeyword=Search&SiteID=msstore&Action=list&categoryID=38336300&keywords=sql&result=).

---

**EDIT**

According to [a forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/c720c294-080d-4e86-af31-c08eec870793):

> I`m not sure what you mean - you ask
>   for Management Studio and there is a
>   download link for SQL Server
>   Management Studio Express.
>
> **Or will you buy a SQL Server Standard,
>   Enterprise or Datacenter Edition -
>   then you have the "normal" SQL Server
>   Management Studio.**

Comment: @grady,, I have did a quick google and found out the above ^ see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can download eval version from this link -

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx

The express edition are the free versions.