# How to Add SSIS to my SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a server running SQL Server 2008 R2, and the Analysis and Integration services are running on that server.

I have on my Windows XP PC Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

In Visual Studio, when I go to open a new Analysis Services project, it lets me. However, if I try to open a new Integration Services project it doesn't let me and at the end it tells me that:

> *To install Integration Services, run SQL Server Setup and select
>   Integration Services.*

So I locate the install media and run Setup and chose this option:

> *New installation or add features to an existing installation.*

However, through the steps, it looks as if it's going to install the server engine on my PC, so I hesitated and stopped the process.

I looked around and found this one [How to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 component only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536023/how-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2008-component-only) that refers to being able to

> *install just the Client/Workstation Components*

but I didn't see that so far.

I also found this: http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/06/03/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-management-studio/ and she says to

> *Run the SQL Server Management Studio installer*

What is she referring to? I don't see that in my media.

I wonder, wouldn't it be logical to start the install process with asking Client components or Server components or both?

Comment: I think that you need to start with Client components. your Intregration services are running on that server.

which version of SQL Server 2008 R2 are you running?

Comment: Please clarify: you are referring to the server running the SQL engine or to my client PC?

Comment: 1. I would reinstall SSMS on client PC..
2. which version of SQL Server 2008 R2 on the server?

Comment: I uninstalled all SQL from my PC, reinstalled, and that did it. Incredible that there's no easier way. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, post an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please uninstall and reinstall SQL Server Management Studio(Client/Workstation Components) on client PC, in order to work with SSIS.

Comment: You seem top be right - I wish I'd seen this sooner!  It appears to install OK if you add it to an existing installation but it just doesn't show up.